# Comparing two lists and ignoring a specific property

Tags: c#, list, generics, comparison, iequalitycomparer

I have two employee lists that I want to get only unique records from but this has a twist to it. Each list has an Employee class in it:

```
public class  Employee
{

// I want to completely ignore ID in the comparison
public int ID{ get; set; }
// I want to use FirstName and LastName in comparison
public string FirstName{ get; set; }
public string LastName{ get; set; }
}
```

The only properties I want to compare on for a match are FirstName and LastName. I want to completely ignore ID in the comparison. The allFulltimeEmployees list has 3 employees in it and the allParttimeEmployees list has 3 employees in it. The first name and last name match on two items in the lists - Sally Jones and Fred Jackson. There is one item in the list that does not match because FirstName is the same, but LastName differs:

```
emp.id = null; // not populated or used in comparison
emp.FirstName = "Joe"; // same
emp.LastName = "Smith"; // different

allFulltimeEmployees.Add(emp);

emp.id = 3; // not used in comparison
emp.FirstName = "Joe"; // a match
emp.LastName = "Williams"; // not a match - different last name

allParttimeEmployees.Add(emp);
```

So I want to ignore the ID property in the class during the comparison of the two lists. I want to flag Joe Williams as a non-match since the last names of Smith and Williams in the two lists do not match.

```
// finalResult should only have Joe Williams in it 

var finalResult = allFulltimeEmployees.Except(allParttimeEmployees);
```

I've tried using an IEqualityComparer but it doesn't work since it is using a single Employee class in the parameters rather than an IEnumerable list:

```
public class EmployeeEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee>
    {
        public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
        {
            if (x.FirstName == y.FirstName && x.LastName == y.LastName)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Employee obj)
        {
            return obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

How can I successfully do what I want and perform this operation? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your idea of using the `IEqualityComparer` is fine, it's your execution that is wrong. Notably, your `GetHashCode` method.

```
public int GetHashCode(Employee obj) 
{ 
    return obj.GetHashCode(); 
}
```

`IEqualityComparer` defines both `Equals` and `GetHashCode` **because both are important.** Do not ignore `GetHashCode` when you implement this interface! It plays a pivotal role on equality comparisons. No, it is not an indication that two items are equal, but it is an indicator that two elements *are not*. Two equal elements *must* return the same hash code. If they do not, they cannot be considered equal. If they do, then they *might* be equal, and equality functions *only then* go on to explore `Equals`.

With your implementation delegating to the `GetHashCode` method of the actual employee object, you are relying upon the implementation that Employee class uses. *Only if* that implementation is overriden will it be useful for you, and *only if* it is using your key fields. *And if it is*, then it is very likely that you did not need to define your own external comparer in the first place!

Build a `GetHashCode` method that factors in your key fields and you will be set.

```
public int GetHashCode(Employee obj)
{
     // null handling omitted for brevity, but you will want to
     // handle null values appropriately

     return obj.FirstName.GetHashCode() * 117 
          + obj.LastName.GetHashCode(); 
}
```

Once you have this method in place, then use the comparer in your call to `Except`.

```
var comparer = new EmployeeEqualityComparer();
var results = allFulltimeEmployees.Except(allParttimeEmployees, comparer);
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony - that was exactly the problem. Once I fixed my GetHashCode method it worked fine. What is the significance of the *117? Just to add further uniqueness to the calculated value? Also, how would I deal with nulls in the GetHashCode method? Thanks again for the answer!

Comment: The math is a nod to implementations such as [those recommended here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode). For more on rules and guidelines for GetHashCode, [this is an excellent read](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx).

Comment: As for nulls, you simply do not want to access properties on null Employee objects, nor would you want to call methods on null properties. So you want to have appropriate null checks in place if you have any concern that nulls may be present.

Answer (score 4):

You can override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your `Employees` class.

For example,

```
    public class Employee
    {

        // I want to completely ignore ID in the comparison
        public int ID { get; set; }
        // I want to use FirstName and LastName in comparison
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var other = obj as Employee;
            return this.FirstName == other.FirstName && this.LastName == other.LastName;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.FirstName.GetHashCode() ^ this.LastName.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

I tested with the following data set:

```
var empList1 = new List<Employee>
{
    new Employee{ID = 1, FirstName = "D", LastName = "M"}, 
    new Employee{ID = 2, FirstName = "Foo", LastName = "Bar"}
};
var empList2 = new List<Employee> 
{ 
    new Employee { ID = 2, FirstName = "D", LastName = "M" }, 
    new Employee { ID = 1, FirstName = "Foo", LastName = "Baz" } 
};

var result = empList1.Except(empList2); // Contained "Foo Bar", ID #2.
```

Comment: This is valid *only if* the ID is *never* a factor in equality comparisons. (However, generally speaking, you tend to think an ID is important. If it can't *identify* an object, what good is it?) In this case, it seems to be a special case scenario that it is excluded for equality comparison, which makes the external comparer the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

your `IEqualityComparer` should work:

```
var finalResult = allFulltimeEmployees.Except(allParttimeEmployees, new EmployeeEqualityComparer());
```

Comment: His current implementation of his comparer would only produce the correct results by accident or redundance. Namely, he would have to have a suitable default implementation of GetHashCode already defined within the class, rendering his external equality comparer rather superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the [IEquatable(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) interface for your `Employee` class. You simply need to provide an implementation for an `Equals()` method, which you can define however you want (i.e. ignoring employee IDs).

> The IEquatable interface is used by generic collection objects such
>   as Dictionary, List, and LinkedList when testing
>   for equality in such methods as Contains, IndexOf, LastIndexOf, and
>   Remove. It should be implemented for any object that might be stored
>   in a generic collection.

Example implementation of the `Equals()` method:

```
public bool Equals(Employee other)
{
   return (other != null) && (FirstName == other.FirstName) && (LastName == other.LastName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant solution, but you could make a function like so

```
public string GetKey(Employee emp)
{
    return string.Format("{0}#{1}", emp.FirstName, emp.LastName)
}
```

and then populate everything in `allFullTimeEmployees` into a `Dictionary<string, Employee>`  where the key of the dictionary is the result of calling `GetKey` on each employee object.  Then you could loop over `allParttimeEmployees` and call `GetKey` on each of those, probing into the dictionary (e.g. using `TryGetValue` or `ContainsKey`), and taking whatever action was necessary on a duplicate, such as removing the duplicate from the dictionary.